# What is causing this C runtime error resulting in garbage numbers in the middle of an array

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm a beginner C developer and am absolutely stumped after encountering a strange error in my C program.
Here is the code I'm having a problem with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void resize(int *array, int newsize) {
  int old_size = sizeof(*array);

  int *temp = malloc(old_size);
  if (temp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
    temp[i] = array[i];
  }

  array = malloc(sizeof(int) * newsize);
  if (array == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
    array[i] = temp[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
  }

  free(temp);
}

int main() {
  int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
  if (arr == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 3;

  printf("Original array:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("index %d element %d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }

  printf("\nNew array:\n");

  int newsize = 30;
  resize(arr, newsize);

  for (int i = 3; i < newsize; i++) {

    arr[i] = i + 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++) {
    printf("index %d element %d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }

  free(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
./a.out
Original array:
index 0 element 1
index 1 element 2
index 2 element 3

New array:
index 0 element 1
index 1 element 2
index 2 element 3
index 3 element 4
index 4 element 5
index 5 element 6
index 6 element 7
index 7 element 8
index 8 element 1701080681
index 9 element 540549240
index 10 element 1835363429
index 11 element 1953391981
index 12 element 892940576
index 13 element 892351545
index 14 element 168441140
index 15 element 16
index 16 element 17
index 17 element 18
index 18 element 19
index 19 element 20
index 20 element 21
index 21 element 22
index 22 element 23
index 23 element 24
index 24 element 25
index 25 element 26
index 26 element 27
index 27 element 28
index 28 element 29
index 29 element 30
```

The program works as expected except for showing garbage numbers at indexes 8-14.
interestingly, the unexpected numbers are always at index 8-14 (no matter the array length) and are always the same numbers.

This is my first ever stack overflow post that I only made because I am seriously confused,
any help is appreciated, thanks!

I have tried inspecting the (existing) values as they are moved to and from the temp array. The numbers remain the same.

(EDIT) - Both of the answers have helped me, thank you to everyone who contributed!

Comment: What does the argument to `malloc` count?

Comment: Given that you have `int *array` in the parameter list, `int old_size = sizeof(*array);` almost certainly sets `old_size` to 4 (and indisputably sets it to `sizeof(int)`.  The array size does not travel with an array passed to a function in C.  You have to provide it explicitly.

Comment: @DavisHerring The total size (in bytes) of the input array

Comment: @JonathanLeffler (sorry Im still new to c) how would I get the size of the array then so I could pass it to the function?

Comment: In the function that defines the array — whether as an automatic array of fixed size, or as a VLA, or dynamically allocates it — you control the size.  The most useful size is usually the number of elements in the array.  For an array of `char` (or `unsigned char` or `signed char`, or any synonym), `sizeof` gives the answer you want.  For bigger types, it gives you the number of bytes, rather than the number of elements.  Often, you have a variable or macro that specifies the size of the array; other times, you might need to use `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))`.

Comment: Note that function parameters, even ones that look like sized arrays, cannot be usefully sized with `sizeof()`.  Also, array declarations like `extern int ext_array[];` cannot be usefully sized.

Comment: One may want to include `int *array` and `size_t size` and `size_t capacity` in one `int` dynamic array `struct`: they are of limited value without each other, it saves you having to use double-pointers, and is generally clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good luck on your journey learning C. There are a few problems I noticed here, and I think I have an explanation for your problem.

---

This part isn't the cause of your problem, but it is something you should be aware of.

```c
int old_size = sizeof(*array);
int *temp = malloc(old_size);
```

This allocates 4 bytes of memory, because that's the size of an integer. It cannot tell you the length of the array. C doesn't store that information at runtime. You'll need to pass that into your resize function as an extra parameter. Otherwise, you're trying to access memory which doesn't belong to temp, because it only has room for one integer.

---

Another problem you should be aware of, although it just happens to work in your case. The last for loop of your `resize` function has the wrong intial value. Assuming you don't want to overwrite your entire array with zeros, you'll need to initialize `i` to `old_size`

```c
for (int i = old_size; i < newsize; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

---

This *is* what I think the problem is.

```c
array = malloc(sizeof(int) * newsize);
```

You never actually freed the original array, so a memory leak occurs here. But more importantly, this won't change the pointer in the main function. That hasn't changed at all. Effectively, you've done this:

```c
void foo(int x) {
    x = 5;
}

void main() {
    int x = 3;
    foo(x);
    // x will still be 3 here
}
```

Now, because your `arr` variable in the main function is unchanged, the loop is accessing memory which doesn't belong to the `arr` array. So the memory allocator still is able to give that memory to other calls to `malloc`. When you called the `printf` function, it started using some of the bytes following the `arr` array, and you accessed those bytes in your for loop.

The solution to this would be to change your `resize` function to take `**int` instead of `*int`.

```c
void resize(int **array, int oldsize, int newsize) {
    temp = malloc(sizeof(int) * oldsize);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++) {
        temp[i] = (*array)[i];
    }

    free(*array);
    *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * newsize);
    if (*array == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++) {
        (*array)[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (int i = oldsize; i < newsize; i++) {
        (*array)[i] = 0;
    }

    free(temp);
}
```

---

You could make this slightly more efficient and a bit cleaner by removing the extra `malloc` call. Like so:

```c
void resize(int **array, int oldsize, int newsize) {
    int *newarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * newsize);
    if (newarray == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++) {
        newarray[i] = (*array)[i];
    }

    for (int i = oldsize; i < newsize; i++) {
        newarray[i] = 0;
    }

    free(*array);
    *array = newarray;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you can use `memcpy` to eliminate one of the for loops. And if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, then you don't need to do any zeroing.

```c
void resize(int **array, int oldsize, int newsize) {
    // calloc initializes the memory with all zeroes
    int *newarray = calloc(sizeof(int) * newsize);
    if (newarray == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy(newarray, *array, sizeof(int) * oldsize);

    free(*array);
    *array = newarray;
}
```

---

Also, you might already know this, but just in case you don't, there's already a function in the standard library called `realloc`. This has the benefit of being able to return the same pointer you had before in some cases, which means nothing needs to be copied. This would also allow you to resize into a smaller array, which your current implementation cannot do without causing undefined behavior.

```c
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * newsize);
if (arr == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate new list memory. Fatal error - crash.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Your `resize` function destroys the original contents of the array. It is not at all similar to `realloc`.

Comment: @paddy It's true that `realloc` has extra functionality which would also be useful to this program. That's another good reason to bring it up here.

Comment: The original code is clearly attempting to preserve the original data, even though there are several bugs in the function. So, if you're gonna show an entire `resize` function as a solution, consider that the OP is gonna expect that behavior and might find your solution confusing. It should also be mentioned that `realloc` can fail, which in your example would mean the pointer is lost and the memory is leaked.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I didn't get that impression because of the entire array being set to zero in the original, but I think that was also a bug. I'll edit this answer.

Comment: You need to look at how it's called in the `main` function and notice that the first few values of the (incorrect) output do hide the fact that this is broken, and they didn't mention it. Also, if the intent is to zero the entire array, there would be no explanation for why such explicit efforts are made to keep the old array hanging around to copy data out of it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct, and I pointed this out in the last paragraph. I don't think the poster actually needs it to do this though, and if not, then it would unnecessary to give a complete `realloc` implementation in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938265/2410359](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938265/2410359) explains many of the problems of OP's code.

Below is an alternative `resize()` function.
Consider using `realloc()`, yet code here will follow OP's `malloc()` approach.

- Call with the *address* of the array.
- Use `size_t` for array sizing rather than `int`.
- Do not assume the current size is less than the new size.
- Allow a size to be zero.
- Check parameters.
- Use `mem...()` to copy , zero fill.
- Since function is particular to `int`, name it so.  Alternative, make a generic function.

```
// Untested code.

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Reallocate an int allocation.
// Return error flag.
bool resize_int(size_t current_size, int **array, size_t new_size) {
  if (array == NULL) {
    return true; // Error, need address of the allocation, not a NULL.
  }

  int *array_new;
  if (new_size > SIZE_MAX/sizeof array_new[0] || current_size > SIZE_MAX/sizeof array_new[0]) {
    return true; // Too big.
  }

  array_new = malloc(sizeof array_new[0] * new_size);
  if (array_new == NULL && new_size > 0) {
    return true; // Allocation failure.
  }

  // Copy first part of *array
  size_t copy_size = current_size < new_size ? current_size : new_size;
  memcpy(array_new, *array, sizeof array_new[0] * copy_size);

  // Zero out new elements
  if (new_size > copy_size) {
    memset(array_new + copy_size, 0, sizeof array_new[0] * (new_size - copy_size));
  }

  free(*array);
  *array = array_new;
  return false; // No errors.
}


// Sample usage.
size_t current_size = 3;
...
size_t newsize = 30;
resize(current_size, &arr, newsize);
```